# Skoda rapid 1.6 diesel, 2013.. engine oil burning

Tags: engine, oil-leak

My vehicle just has first service two months back. And then engine was burning the oil. I didn't see any smoke coming backside of my vehicle. There is no mileage problem or pickup or power problems. Everything's fine. I didn't see any leakages too. But sometimes in running randomly the engine doesn't move with the accelerator. It just moves in same speed. It doesn't responds to the accelerator. What will be the problem and how much cost it takes to repair for individual problems? Can you help me with this?

Comment: How much oil is it burning, exactly? If it doesn't respond to the accelerator, maybe the RPMs are too low and you're simply lugging the engine? Does downshifting help?

Comment: Till now I didn't put any pressures on the engine. After the first service I just used it for 2000kms. Then I noticed that the engine was running roughly, I checked the oil lever and it's empty, the oil was just a bit to the lever. Then I put another 4 litres oil in it. Then again after 2000kms the oil was empty. That's the situation now.

Answer (score 1):

If the oil levels go to the empty mark in just 2000kms, then we definitely have a problem here. Generally the 1.5/1.6 engines run healthy for around 8K-10K kms without oil levels dipping drastically or the oil getting burnt. The only visible difference we get on running on the same oil for 10K kms are that the oil gets black in color and also loses viscosity. Thus, it is advised to change the oil at around 5-6K kms (non-synthetic) and around 8-10K (synthetic).
Coming back to your problem, I would suggest you to look out for these symptoms, for diagnosing whether the oil is getting burnt or its getting leaked:

1. Engine Temperature-If the engine heats up abnormally after a normal ride (temperature meter above the middle mark towards HOT), then the oil pump may have issues. The oil is not getting circulated evenly across all the nooks and corners on the engine block and thus local regions of engine are getting extremely hot, and thereby the oil is getting burnt.
2. Color of the smoke from exhaust: If the smoke is black in color under normal acceleration, then there is a high chance of oil getting burnt in the engine.
3. Fuel Efficiency: If you are burning oil in the engine, then your fuel economy will fall drastically.

So, if you see any of the above points to be present in your car, then you can be sure that the oil is getting burnt in your engine.

However, if you do not see any of the above symptoms, there you do not have the problem of oil burning, now the investigation can shift to finding out if there is any leakage. Here's how you can find it:

1. Park the car overnight in a clean garage. Check the garage floor on the following morning. If you see oil marks (don't confuse the AC drained water to be oil), then the sump or an oil line is leaking. Easy job, just find out the leak and plug it.
2. If you do not see any oil mark, then you can put the car in a dyno, rev the engine and check if there any leak from the engine block due to a blown gasket. You will need a trained technician to find it out.

If you still do not find any matching symptoms, then I would suggest you get the compression checked in all cylinders. There may be an issue with the piston rings placement and thus the oil can be leaking from improperly set pistons rings. As you mention that your engine is quite new, there can be a problem with the way the engine was 'run-in' during its 'breaking-in' stage. This problem can be diagnosed by checking the compression of the engine.

All the best!